The Expansion of a Congruence of Outgoing Light Rays in Schwarzschild Metric - Kruskal Coordinates
Background:
The Schwarzschild metric expressed in Kruskal coordinates is $$ds^2=-\frac{32M^3}{r}e^{-r/2M} dU dV + r^2 d\Omega^2,$$ where $r=r(U,V)$ is defined through the implicit relation $$e^{-r/2M}\left(1-\frac{r}{2M}\right)=UV,~~~~\rightarrow(1)$$ and $d\Omega^2$ is the metric on a round sphere of unit radius, $$d\Omega^2=d\theta^2+\sin^2{\theta}d\phi^2.$$
Outgoing light rays are represented by constant $U$ curves. Hence, they have a tangent vector, $$k_\mu=-\partial_\mu U.$$ In Kruskal coordinates, $\{U,V,\theta,\phi\}$, $$k_\mu=(-1,0,0,0).$$
Question:
In chapter five of the Relativist's Toolkit book by Eric Poisson, it is claimed that the expansion of such a congruence is given by (Eq. 5.15), $$\boxed{\Theta_{\mathrm{book}}=\nabla_\mu k^\mu=-\frac{U}{2Mr}.}$$ His conclusion then is that the expansion switches signs at the event horizon, $r=2M$.
When I attempted to verify the result myself, I found a different result:
$$\boxed{\Theta_{\mathrm{mine}}=\nabla_\mu k^\mu=\frac{1}{2}\frac{e^{r/M}}{r-4M}U.}$$
My Solution:
Here is my approach so you can tell me where I went wrong:
$$\Theta\equiv\nabla_\mu k^\mu=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\partial_\mu\left(\sqrt{-g}k^\mu\right).~~~~\rightarrow(2)$$
Now, $$g\equiv\det{g}=\det\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -\frac{16M^3}{r}e^{-r/2M} &0&0\\
-\frac{16M^3}{r}e^{-r/2M} & 0&0&0\\
0&0&r^2&0\\
0&0&0&r^2 \sin^2\theta
\end{bmatrix}=-\left(\frac{16M^3}{r}e^{-r/2M} r r \sin\theta\right)^2.$$
Therefore,
$$\sqrt{-g}=16M^3e^{-r/2M} r \sin\theta.~~~~\rightarrow(3)$$
To get $k^\mu$, we need the inverse metric, which is
$$g^{\mu\nu}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -\frac{r}{16M^3}e^{r/2M} &0&0\\
-\frac{r}{16M^3}e^{r/2M} & 0&0&0\\
0&0&\frac{1}{r^2}&0\\
0&0&0&\frac{1}{r^2 \sin^2\theta}
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then, $$k^\mu=g^{\mu\nu}k_\nu=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -\frac{r}{16M^3}e^{r/2M} &0&0\\
-\frac{r}{16M^3}e^{r/2M} & 0&0&0\\
0&0&\frac{1}{r^2}&0\\
0&0&0&\frac{1}{r^2 \sin^2\theta}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
\frac{r}{16M^3}e^{r/2M}\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}.~~~~\rightarrow(4)$$
Substituting Equations (3) and (4) into Equation (2), I obtain
$$\begin{split}
\nabla_\mu k^\mu&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\partial_V\left(\sqrt{-g}k^V\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{16M^3e^{-r/2M} r \sin\theta}\partial_V\left(16M^3e^{-r/2M} r \sin\theta\frac{r}{16M^3}e^{r/2M}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{16M^3 e^{-r/2M} r}\partial_V\left(r^2\right).
\end{split}$$
Thus, $$\nabla_\mu k^\mu=\frac{e^{r/2M}}{8M^3}\frac{\partial r}{\partial V}.~~~~\rightarrow(5)$$
Finally, we can differentiate the implicit equation (1) with respect to $V$ while holding $U$ constant to get $\partial r/\partial V$:
$$\begin{split}
\frac{\partial}{\partial V}\left(e^{-r/2M}\left(1-\frac{r}{2M}\right)\right)&=\frac{\partial}{\partial V}\left(UV\right)\\
\frac{-e^{-r/2M}}{2M}\frac{\partial r}{\partial V}\left(1-\frac{r}{2M}\right)-\frac{e^{-r/2M}}{2M}\frac{\partial r}{\partial V}&=U\\
\frac{-e^{-r/2M}}{2M}\frac{\partial r}{\partial V}\left(2-\frac{r}{2M}\right)&=U.
\end{split}$$
Solving for $\partial r/\partial V$, I get
$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial V}=\frac{4M^2}{r-4M}e^{r/2M}U.~~~~\rightarrow(6)$$
Substituting (6) into (5), I get
$$\Theta_{\mathrm{mine}}=\nabla_\mu k^\mu=\frac{1}{2}\frac{e^{r/M}}{r-4M}U.$$
Can anyone point out where I went wrong? Or if the book is wrong on that part? If so, how does the interpretation changes regarding the sign flip at the horizon?

I agree with $\text{div}(k)=\frac{e^{r/2M}}{8M^3}\frac{\partial r}{\partial V}$, which is your equation $(5)$, however, your very defining equation $(1)$ for $r$ has a sign error. It should be
\begin{align}
e^{\color{red}{+}r/2M}\left(1-\frac{r}{2M}\right)&=UV.
\end{align}
With this $+$ sign, there will be an extra cancellation when doing the differentiation, and now you’ll find that $\frac{\partial r}{\partial V}=-\frac{4M^2U}{re^{r/2M}}$, and thus $\text{div}(k)=-\frac{U}{2Mr}$, as claimed in the book.
